# Android restarts when I press "Turn on USB storage" button

Tags: usb-connection-mode, reboot, usb-mass-storage

I have an ACME TB709-3G tablet with Android 4.2.2 installed on it. I was able to connect this tablet to my Ubuntu 14.04 TLS laptop before, but recently when I press the "Turn on USB storage" button, Android restarts.

What is the problem and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Resetting might solve your problem

Comment: Tried it before. No change.

Comment: Did you enable restart on "unauthorized" USB connection? Also what tablet? Custom or stock ROM? Debugging turned on? Can you access through ADB?

Comment: How can I check this "restart on unauthorized USB connection" option? I can not find it. My tablet is ACME TB709-3G. Debugging option is not available in my settings!!!

Comment: Goto settings>about phone/tablet scroll down to bottom and tap on "build" 7 times. Back once to main settings page. Scroll to developer options. Check your setting in there.

Comment: Ok. Debugging is turned off and I have no option like "restart on unauthorized USB connection" there.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN [Athar](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/116909/athar) can't comment(posted it in an answer) but wants to say, I assume to you: *"There is no such option like "restart on unauthorized USB connection' in Developer options. My phone is rooted Micromax canvas 4 A210. 4.2.2 Jellybean."*

Answer (score 1):

## options for fixing USB not authorized

(On device)

1. Go to *settings/about device*, scroll to "**build**"

   - Tap on build 7 times to enable *developer options*
   - Back out to main settings screen, goto developer options
   - Enable USB connection

---

or

---

(On device)

2. Using a file manager that has root access

   - Remove "**adb_key**"

   `/data/misc/adb/adb_key`

   - Reboot your phone and try connect again.
   - The confirmation message should popup after a short time.

---

or

---

(On PC)

3. Remove the "**RSA keys**" from *SDK settings*

   `~/.android/adbkey`

   - Start up ADB

   `$ adb kill-server`

   `$ adb start-server`

   - Plug device back into **USB port** (*not hub*) and wait.
   - Confirmation notice will popup after a short time period.

---

or

---

4. You can try [this](https://www.linux-tips.org/article/130/fixing-android-adb-usb-device-permissions). The steps are more involved, requires *device and vendor IDs*

   - this has been included because it is helpful and a reference
   - steps haven't been included in the answer because it is off topic

---

- in step 3 (~) is the location of your SDK installation
- make sure you have the latest adb executable installed
- make sure you have the latest drivers for your device
- ***make a backup before performing any of the above steps***